# Looking for the title of an old Robert Heinlein book

Tags: story-identification

Robert Heinlein wrote a novel (one of his earlier novels, I believe) in which China had invaded the USA and the Americans, in order to combat and confuse their invaders, developed a weapon (tool?) which could change matter into just about anything.
I am looking for the title of that book and I apologize for the short summary (which may be only partially accurate -- I am old and my memory is fading).  But I'd like to get a copy of that old book.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: How does one go about something like this? Do we merge the details so that people who search for a book where "China invaded the US" they still find the question?

Comment: @Edlothiad - marking duplicate is enough, the goal isnt closing or merging questions but just linking them up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No sooner after I wrote this, I was discussing this issue with an old friend and he gave me a clue.  The clue led to the answer which follows:

***[Sixth Column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_Column)***
(also known as ***The Day After Tomorrow***)

[image: Sixth Column title]

Hope that helps.

Thanks

Comment: I was actually entering my answer when you put yours in. 41s.

Comment: It was luck -- my grey memory cells kicked in just in time. Not bad for a guy 60+ years old.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

I suspect that you are thinking of [*The Day After Tomorrow*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6129), also published as *Sixth Column*. In that book, the "Pan-Asians" conquered the US, and a small research lab discovered some technobabble that allowed for a wide range of effects that were quite frankly unbelievable. The few people at the lab 'prosecuted the war' by creating a religion based around the 'priests' being able to use the effects of the technobabble, and then used the religion to ultimately overthrow the Pan-Asian regime.

Comment: You are correct Jeff.  I had just remembered it ... Thx.

Comment: @tale852150  -  if this is the book you were searching for, would you consider marking it as accepted, by clicking the check mark near it?

Comment: @Gallifreian - done ... :-)

Comment: @tale852150  -  I only asked so I could mark this as a duplicate *evil laugh*

Comment: @TimE.Lord Why get this one accepted when the OP had already added a [self-answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/150050/21267)?

Comment: @Möoz - It's not other commenters that decide which answer gets accepted, it's the querent xirself. Direct your question to tale852150.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Don't get me wrong, hats off to you for taking the effort to post a good answer. I'm directing my question at Galli since he's the one who promoted the OP to accept _this_ particular answer, even though it was posted _after_ the OP's own answer (which can only be correct, since, well, they're the OP).

Comment: @Möoz - could be for no other reason than Tim hadn't refreshed and seen the self-answer before posting the comment.